# Updating text displayed on the terminal

Tags: c, arrays, linux, printf, output

I'm attempting to create a game of life program in C, but i'm not very familiar with a process to update the output displayed on the terminal.

So, for example, I will have a 2d char array, where each element will contain either a '#' or a '-'. I will print this array onto the screen, but rather than printing a new 2d array every time there is a state change, I want to overwrite the old array in the terminal with the new state.

I have looked for ways to do this, but haven't had much luck. The closest I have found is a carriage return in the printf function (\r), but hopefully someone can tell me the best way to do this.

Specifically, how could I print out a 2d array on the screen, change the elements of the array, and print out the new array ON TOP of the old one, ie, overwrite it.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What do you mean by on top?

Comment: Windows, Linux, iOS... ?

Comment: Sorry, Linux platform

Comment: Okay, do you see anything in either of the answers so far posted?  Some feedback on these comments and/or the answers would be good.  That way if we are missing the mark, you can let us know  where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(some of these links, code snippets are Linux, and others are Windows)
***Given your specific questions***, (and assuming you do know how to write an array to the console) :

***1)*** write the first array.
***2)*** Then Clear The Console (or *over write* the console)
Something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   system("cls");
}
```

Or write the following to stdout:  (Linux)

```
write(1,"\E[H\E[2J",7);
```

which is what /usr/bin/clear does except it does not create another process.
***Or both:***

```
 void clear_screen()
 {
  #ifdef WINDOWS
     system ( "CLS" );
  #else
     // Assume POSIX
     system ( "clear" );
  #endif
 }
```

***[More Options Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261)***

***3)*** write the next array

Comment: Ryyker, apologies for not commenting sooner, have been at work. This looks like it might be exactly what i've been looking for! I will try this out later and tick the solution if all good. Thanks :)

Comment: @syco_link - Yes, that work thing kind of gets in the way sometimes.

Comment: Cleared the screen perfectly, exactly what I was after! Is there any chance you could explain the expression in the write function, or point me towards some documentation for it? Thank you!

Comment: Search for "\E[H\E[2J"   ***[HERE](http://linuxgazette.net/115/okopnik1.html)***.  It is essentially shell scripting.  Lots written on it, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

printf ("#####-----\r");
printf ("-#####----\r");

}
```

Not sure if I really answered your question. And if this is not your answer then you are definitely looking for something like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Comment: Sorry, the array is 2d so it might be a 10 x 10 grid on the terminal. As far as i'm aware \r will only deal with one line and no more, but I shall look into ncurses, thanks!